# Как залить SVG фоновой картинкой, без искажения фонового изображения?

Tags: html, css, svg

**Здравствуйте!** Есть следующая конструкция:

```css
div {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>

  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" width="400px" height="55px" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 47.22 6.49" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" <defs>

<pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100%" height="100%"> <image xlink:href="https://i.ibb.co/XFK2qJK/pattern.jpg" width="500px" height="500px" />
</pattern>

</defs>

<path class="fil0" d="M44.45 0c0.27,1.28 1.41,2.24 2.77,2.24l0 1.42c-1.56,0 -2.83,1.27 -2.83,2.83l-41.56 0c0,-1.56 -1.27,-2.83 -2.83,-2.83l0 -1.42c1.35,0 2.5,-0.96 2.77,-2.24 1.73,2.13 10.4,3.74 20.84,3.74 10.44,0 19.11,-1.61 20.84,-3.74z" fill="url(#img1)"/>

</svg>
</div>
<div>
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/XFK2qJK/pattern.jpg">
</div>
```

Необходимо залить SVG картинкой, при этом чтобы картинка которая используется в качестве фонового изображения, не была растянута. т.е. если фоновое изображение 500x500px, то оно должно таким и оставаться (500x500).

Что я делаю неправильно? Почему у меня в примере реальный размер фонового изображения 500x500px но когда я добавляю его в SVG оно растягивается примерно до 4000x4000px. Помогите исправить ошибку.

Ниже в примере добавлено для наглядности просто изображение, так как оно должно быть, а в SVG сразу видно что оно растянуто

**Благодарю за ответ!**

Comment: mask используйте - он удобнее ...

Comment: хотя и pattern тоже можно использовать : https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/GREpVzV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SVG` имеет `viewBox="0 0 47.22 6.49"`, то есть от изображения 500X500 нам видно только 47.22X6.49. `ViewBox` в аккурат захватывает ваш путь по габаритам, а атрибут `width` растягивает это "окно" до 400px. Одновременно растягивается и кусочек изображения, естественно.

Если не искать легких путей (давно хотел попробовать), то можно распарсить путь и отмасштабировать его на уровне строки `d="M...z"`. Нужный масштаб получаю делением реальной ширины `SVG` на ширину `viewBox`:

```
scale = svg.getBoundingClientRect().width/svg.getAttribute('viewBox').split(' ')[2];
```

Так как сам путь уже будет растянут на ширину `SVG`, то атрибут `viewBox` в конце удаляем. Ведь в паре с `width` он работает только для правильного размещения пути. Подстраиваться под ширину контейнера SVG не будет.

Хотя viewBox можно и оставить, изменяя и его размеры и начальные точки:

```
svg.setAttribute('viewBox', svg.getAttribute('viewBox').split(' ').map(i => i * scale).join(' '));
```

```js
let svg = document.querySelector('svg');
let pathEl = svg.querySelector('path');

let path = pathEl.getAttribute('d');
let pathWidth = svg.getAttribute('viewBox').split(' ')[2];
let svgWidth = svg.getBoundingClientRect().width;
let scale = svgWidth/pathWidth;

let path1 = path.replace(/(?<=[^\d.-]*)([\d.-]+)(?=[^\d.-]*)/g, m => m*scale);

svg.removeAttribute('viewBox');
pathEl.setAttribute('d', path1);
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 47.22 6.49" width="400px"> 
    <defs>
        <pattern id="_img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100%" height="100%"> <image xlink:href="https://i.ibb.co/XFK2qJK/pattern.jpg" width="500px" height="500px" />
        </pattern>
    </defs>

    <path class="fil0" d="M44.45 0c0.27,1.28 1.41,2.24 2.77,2.24l0 1.42c-1.56,0 -2.83,1.27 -2.83,2.83l-41.56 0c0,-1.56 -1.27,-2.83 -2.83,-2.83l0 -1.42c1.35,0 2.5,-0.96 2.77,-2.24 1.73,2.13 10.4,3.74 20.84,3.74 10.44,0 19.11,-1.61 20.84,-3.74z" fill="url(#_img1)"/>

</svg>
```

Или гораздо проще установить `1/масштаб` самому изображению. Чтобы оно уменьшилось с `500*500` до соответствующего `viewBox` размера.

```js
let svg = document.querySelector('svg');

let viewWidth = svg.getAttribute('viewBox').split(' ')[2];
let svgWidth = svg.getBoundingClientRect().width;
let scale = svgWidth/viewWidth;

svg.querySelector('pattern > image').setAttribute('transform', `scale(${1/scale})`);
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 47.22 6.49" width="400px"> 
    <defs>
        <pattern id="_img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100%" height="100%"> <image xlink:href="https://i.ibb.co/XFK2qJK/pattern.jpg" width="500px" height="500px" />
        </pattern>
    </defs>

    <path class="fil0" d="M44.45 0c0.27,1.28 1.41,2.24 2.77,2.24l0 1.42c-1.56,0 -2.83,1.27 -2.83,2.83l-41.56 0c0,-1.56 -1.27,-2.83 -2.83,-2.83l0 -1.42c1.35,0 2.5,-0.96 2.77,-2.24 1.73,2.13 10.4,3.74 20.84,3.74 10.44,0 19.11,-1.61 20.84,-3.74z" fill="url(#_img1)"/>

</svg>
```

Comment: Ну а Александр придет, расставит атрибуты правильно и будет нормальный ответ, на уровне XML, а вручную на JS.

Comment: Большое спасибо за исчерпывающий ответ и разъяснение в чем была ошибка! Отдельное большое спасибо за рабочее решение задачи! Вопрос, для понимания на будущее: как правильно экспортировать CSV из графических редакторов чтобы не было заморочек с `viewBox`? чтобы он совпадал по размерам с фактическим размером изображения, если конечно это корректный вопрос. Можно ли для того чтобы задать размер SVG использовать только `viewBox` без дополнительных атрибутов таких как `width`?

Comment: По-моему разные редакторы по-разному себя ведут в этом смысле. Я работаю в Corel, выставляю размер страницы (рабочей области) так, чтобы путь нормально располагался или наоборот, центр пути на 0,0. При экспортировании можно изменить размеры (в пикселях). Тогда на выходе получаю `viewBox="0 0 width height" width="widthpx" height="heightpx"`. Есть редакторы, например такое в Inkscape, которые изменения сохраняют в атрибуты transform, scale. А сам путь при его масштабировании в редакторе или перемещении оставляют прежним. Corel успешно перестраивает сам путь.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, тоже делаю в Corel, но не мог понять от куда такие странные значения в  `viewBox`, точнее до этого не задавался вопросом, с CSV приходятся иметь дело очень редко) Сейчас буду экспериментировать с размерами страницы  по этому вопросу